# How can I pass a very long string from one page to another?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I'm making a data visualisation tool that works using SVG, d3.js and JQuery. I am currently making a feature to export (and download) as an SVG file:

```
// Code on main page
var svg = $("#svg-wrap").html();
var win = window.open("export.php?svg=" + svg, '_blank'); // _blank means export.php opens in a new tab
win.focus;

// Code in export.php
<?php
ob_start();
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=data.svg");
$svg = $_GET["svg"];
echo stripslashes($svg);
?>
```

This doesn't work though, because although some of the SVG is passed through, the full code is too long for a query string (or so it seems).

Is there some way that I can fix this? I could use compression, but that would only shrink it up to a limit and I think it would probably still be too long - the SVG code could be hundreds of lines :( .

Comment: use POST with the string in the body of the request.
GET requests are usually limited to (up to) 8KB

Comment: How would I send the POST data?

Comment: you will have to configure your export.php file to handle the POST data. you can send the post data as form data or JSON, XML, whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most UAs put limits on GET requests. Use POST instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in session variable and access it on other page... but not the best practice though...

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the limitation,

a browser can have a limit, for post vs get

a proxy can have a limit, for post vs get

a web server can have a limit, for post vs get

the application itself can set a limit...

etc

As suggested, you could go with writing a svg file and send the url instead.

How big is the svg file?

Comment: It can vary, as the user inputs their own data. At max it could be at least 100 LOC though.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to handle the communication between your main app window and your popup, this way you could just stay on the client side only.